# How to make sure all sql statements are executed else roolback

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have few SQL statements.

```
copy into STG_PB(VAR,FILE_NAME, LINE_NUMBER) 
  from (
      select $1,metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number
      from @investor_stage_s3// 
)

delete from stg_pb1
insert into stg_pb1 values (....)
```

So daily I get loads of data from s3 to be loaded into the database.
In my SQL statement, I am using a delete statement, therefore if I get any error in the insert statement, all my previous data will be lost. How DO I make sure, if an error occurs roll back to previous data?

Thanks,
Xi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [transactions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#transactions):

> A transaction is a sequence of SQL statements that are processed as **an atomic unit**. All statements in the transaction are either applied (i.e. committed) or undone (i.e. rolled back) together.

and
[Allowing Statement Errors to Abort Transactions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/transactions.html#allowing-statement-errors-to-abort-transactions):

> To allow a statement error within a transaction to abort the transaction, set the TRANSACTION_ABORT_ON_ERROR parameter at the session or account level.

```
ALTER SESSION SET TRANSACTION_ABORT_ON_ERROR = TRUE;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;
-- DML 1
-- DML 2
COMMIT;
```

Wrapping everything with Snowflake Scripting block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE t1(i INT);

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRANSACTION;
  
  INSERT INTO t1 SELECT 1;
  INSERT INTO t1 SELECT 1/0;
  
  COMMIT;
  RETURN 'Success';
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHER THEN
  ROLLBACK;
  RETURN 'Error';
END;
$$;

SHOW TRANSACTIONS;
SELECT * FROM t1;
```

Comment: can we set TRANSACTION_ABORT_ON_ERROR globally on account level ?

Comment: @AnumSheraz Yes, [TRANSACTION_ABORT_ON_ERROR](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html#transaction-abort-on-error): `Session — Can be set for Account » User » Session`